# Set default Status bar style to .lightContent but and also allow for a dark override on some view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I working on a huge app loads of view controllers, the app currently sets in status bar style in the plist using:

```
Status bar style = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

New features require me to have some status bars in the dark default style.

So to summarize I need all the app with a default .lightContent and about 10VCs with an override to .default/dark

To start with I need to set the plist to:

```
View controller-based status bar appearance = YES
```

but once I do this many of the status bars in the app change to the .default / dark style.

I can change this style in every VC using:

```
 override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

but in an app this big, this would be impractical.

I've tried quite a few extensions to override behavior, but since these are instance methods they can't be overriden like this:

```
    extension UIViewController
    {
        override open var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
         }
     }
```

You can use this extension:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    override open var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
        return topViewController?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .default
    }
}
```

But it only works on VC's in NavControllers and you need to set every single rootVC to .lightContent

Comment: When you changed "View controller-based status bar appearance" to YES, did you leave the "Status bar style = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent" setting in place or did you remove it?

Comment: I left it as "UIStatusBarStyleLightContent"

Comment: You can use your extension. Just check if topViewController is one of the controllers and return default, otherwise return lightContent.

Answer (score 0):

The extension you provided should work.

```
extension UINavigationController {
  open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    switch topViewController {
      case is DarkContentVC1, is DarkContentVC2, is DarkContentVC3:
        return .default
      default:
        return .lightContent
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually wrote the question wrong and have edited it correctly now.
The issue with this approach is that it only works if the VCs are in a navController and also that setting the style in an extension is not intuitive for future devs.
Good solution for smaller apps though!

Answer (score 0):

After much research it turns out that setting `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES` changes the paradigm of how the status bar is manipulated. It set's it to `default` which automatically configures it to the expected style, it also allows for overriding within individual VC's.

To obtain the goal of setting the whole app to `lightContent` as the default style, the best solution would be to create a subclass of UIViewController for all VC's in your app with that functionality.

A second solution would be to manually change all the root view controllers.